# Automatically link newly created logic apps to an existing alert rule

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have created an Alert action group which will simply call a "error" logic app when the conditions are met. And I have set up an event grid which will be called whenever an logic app gets created for the first time.
Now the challenge is that I want to somehow automatically link this newly created logic app to the action group.
I have searched for way to do this but had no luck, anyone knows if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

One way of updating an action group would be by using the management API, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/action-groups/create-or-update).

However, you might want to think about this a bit differently.
How are you going to deploy everything?
Assuming you're not going to be doing this manually, you will be using ARM-/Bicep-files. So, you could include the configuration of an action group in these deployment files.
Meaning, when you initially deploy the Logic App, it will immediately be added to an action group, allowing it to trigger the required alerts. Next to that, it also allows you to create the event subscriptions in your Azure Event Grid topic.
This way you avoid *missing* the first alert because the action group wasn't updated before the first run of the Logic App.

*The template to create an action group can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/2019-06-01/actiongroups).

The template to create an event grid subscription can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.eventgrid/eventsubscriptions).*

Comment: Yes doing it during the deploy would make sense. Do you know how to add a logic app to an action group when deploying it?
I tried looking through the logic app template but did not find any field regarding action group. @Maxim_Braekman

Comment: You'll have to include it in the creation of the action group within your Bicep/ARM-files, so not within the template of the Logic App itself.  

You can have a look at the documentation-link I shared earlier related to the action group, but below snippet should help as well:  
"webhookReceivers": [  
  {  
    "name": "LogicApp.Webhook",  
    "serviceUri": "[listCallbackURL(concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Logic/workflows', variables('LogicApp.Name'))), '/triggers/manual'), '2016-06-01').value]",  
    "useCommonAlertSchema": true,  
    "useAadAuth": false  
  }  
]